# Get Last Modified Date on Partitioned Data Using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, last-modified

I am ultimately trying to get the names of the partitions (ie DATE_ID=20211004) that have been modified within the last 24 hours. I've tried using the Get Metadata activity, but it seems to only iterate partition folders, and not the files within the partitioned folders. I need to get the last modified date of the partitioned files within the folders, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Folder structure:

product_data/

|---------DATE_ID=20211002/

|---------|---------part-00011-tid-345678900-abc123-6793-1.c000.snappy.parquet

|---------|---------committed_123456789

|---------DATE_ID=20211003/

|---------|---------part-00086-tid-345678900-abc123-6756-2.c000.snappy.parquet

|---------|---------committed_123456789

|---------DATE_ID=20211004/

|---------|---------part-00042-tid-345678900-abc123-6712-1.c000.snappy.parquet

|---------|---------committed_123456789

In the example above, I'd like to get the last modified date and full name of each of the parquet files.

I've tried a variety of For Each + get Metadata activity combinations such as the one below:

https://ibb.co/B4vMF6j

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT I have yet to try it! It does seem like it will work! I plan to try it mid-next week. I needed to move forward with other pipelines/processes before doubling back. I will update you! Thank you for the thorough response! Do you know why a copy activity with partitioned data might fail? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/582075/error-2200-copy-activity-partitioned-parquet-colum.html

Comment: I have answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69522310/add-azure-blob-partitions-to-azure-sql-table/69528825#:~:text=If%20you%20see%20this%20error%3A   It is mostly a schema mismatch, try reset and import schema in mapping section.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set **Start time (UTC)** to `@getPastTime(24,'Hour')` and leave the **End time (UTC)** as NULL to fetch all the files modified within last 24hrs from current timestamp. Using this would only output childitems, that are files and not folders. This is by design.

Create source dataset with path being the root for partitioned data. Use `Get Metadata` activity to list the files in that folder.

[image]

Assign the output list of files to an array variable:

```
@activity('Get Metadata').output.childItems
```

[image]

Next, you can use the meta data option **lastModified** to get the Last modified datetime of each file or folder.

Inside `foreach` activity `@variables('items')`, create a **clone** of source file and add a **parameter** to dynamically get the files based on each file we receive inside foreach.

[image]

[image]

Inside `foreach activity`:

[image]

We then append these `lastmodified` timestamp received to another variable (*you can customize this as per your need*)

```
 @concat(item().name, '  ', 'LastModified:' , activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified)
```

[image]

Finally to list all the results, store the **result** from appended variable to result variable named `final`.

```
   {
    "name": "final",
    "value": [
        "SourceAAD.csv  LastModified:2021-09-29T13:15:07Z",
        "mysource.csv  LastModified:2021-09-27T11:56:33Z",
        "new adf.xlsx  LastModified:2021-09-29T13:16:01Z",
        "sourceDataTime.parquet  LastModified:2021-09-13T05:42:43Z",
        "table3_CustomerAddress.csv  LastModified:2021-10-04T06:01:12Z",
        "table4_product.csv  LastModified:2021-10-04T06:01:13Z",
        "table5_ProductCategory.csv  LastModified:2021-10-04T06:01:12Z",
        "table6_ProductDescription.csv  LastModified:2021-10-04T06:01:12Z",
        "testSource.json  LastModified:2021-08-30T04:19:54Z",
        "testSource.txt  LastModified:2021-08-30T04:17:56Z",
        "userdata2.parquet  LastModified:2021-09-13T03:57:27Z",
        "userdataCopy.parquet  LastModified:2021-09-13T03:57:28Z",
        "userdataOriginal.parquet  LastModified:2021-09-13T03:56:51Z"
    ]
}
```

[image]