# Get last modified of nested file

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, last-modified

**I am trying to get the last modified date of files in nested folders and only copy the files that have been modified in the last 10 days.**

Folder structure:

container: home

product_data/

|---------20221020/

|---------|---------20221020/

|---------|---------|---------product_data_20221020_20221020.parquet

|---------20221021/

|---------|---------20221021/

|---------|---------|---------product_data_20221021_20221021.parquet

|---------20231102/

|---------|---------20231102/

|---------|---------|---------product_data_20231102_20231102.parquet

**the 20231102 parquet file is the only one that should be copied because this file was last modified on Nov-7 (The last modified date does not match the date of the file).**

I've messed with a similar issue before: [Get Last Modified Date on Partitioned Data Using Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443673/get-last-modified-date-on-partitioned-data-using-azure-data-factory)

My current issue is that I can't filter the files at all.

**Image 1:** Pipeline Overview
[image: pipeline overview]

**Image 2:** Get Metadata Config
[image: get metadata config]

**Image 3:** Parent Dataset (root folder)
[image: parent dataset (root folder)]

**Image 4:** For Loop
[image: for loop]

**Image 5:** Get Metadata inside the for loop
[image: Get file metadata inside the for loop]

**Image 6:** Dataset for Get Metadata inside the for loop
[image]

**Image 7:** Parameters for Dataset for Get Metadata inside the for loop
[image]

**Image 8:** Get Metadata output inside the for loop

[image]

Because the "Filter by last modified" on the Get Metadata inside the foor loop doesn't seem to work, I also tried adding a filter and tried setting the variable (to debut), but both fail.

**Filter Config**
items: `@activity('Get Files Metadata').output.itemName`
Condition: `@greater(activity('Get Files Metadata').output.lastModified, addMinutes(utcNow(), -30))`

**Image 9:** Filter Output (Ignore the itemscount)
[image]

**Image 10:** Filter Error

[image]

**Image 11:** Set Variable Config
[image]

**Image 12:** Set Variable Error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get the last modified date of files in nested folders** you need to use get metadata activity and ForLoop with appropriate parameters.

- First take a GetMetadata activity to get the subfolders of **product_data** folder.
  [image]
  Dataset For It:
  [image]
- Pass Output of this activity to ForLoop activity to Iterate on each sub-folder.
  [image]
- Inside ForLoop take a GetMetadata activity to get the Files from subfolders of product_data folder and get the files which are modified in last 10 days  with `Filter by last modified`  parameter where Start time is `@getPastTime(10,'Day')` and End time is `utcNow()`.
  [image]
  Dataset for it:
  [image]

**This will Give you array of Files from the folder which are modified in last 10 days.**